# Mask dynamic logo using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

I am trying to detect and hide a logo that dynamically positioned in a video.

In this video the logo is positioned at the top and after a few minutes down etc.

it's possible to detect every time the logo when it changes place and hide it with ffmpeg?

I tried with delogo but I must tell the position x/y, so it is not possible in my case!

Thank you very much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: It cannot and should not be done. Ignore the everything after this.

Simple idea but likely a complex execution.

I would be shocked if ffmpeg had functionality to do this in a strait-forward manner. You could manually find every logo shift, use ffmpeg to cut the video on those points, manually use your delogo tool for each, then concat them back together again?

If you want to automate this then you're likely doing to have to do a bit of image processing coding. I'm not going to code it but I'll go through a few highlights.

First, ask what you are looking for?

Is the logo a static block that covers what it is over? Is it slightly transparent? Does it change size? Does it change in intensity?

I don't know how much effort went into creating the logo so I can only make guesses.

If its static and entirely in the foreground, then this is a simple search followed by a replacement with whatever you want. easy

If its slightly transparent but of constant size, you will want to reverse-engineer the template they used, search each frame for that pattern, then undo it.

If they got fancier and you want this to be automated then you'll be delving into machine learning and more advanced techniques.

I can think of a whole plethora of nice features for an application like this but that's enough to likely make a start.

Comment: This is not really the answer but just your comments and additional questions, you have to come with a solution or better use just comments. Thanks

Comment: You are completely right. I'll just change my 3 year old answer to it cannot and should not be done. Thank you for suppressing casual conversation.

Comment: Your last edit is just one year before my comment, so why are you talking about three years?

Comment: Yes and my edit was a response to your complaint of it not being an answer. So I answered the question. Three years was in the context of when the question was first responded to.